# Can you send an image as part of the response to a slack slash command?

Tags: slack, slack-api

What I want to do is for a user to use a slash command with an argument, and for me to return an image based off of the information in the slash command argument.

Looking at the slack API documentation, it appears that the only way to send an image as a response to a request coming from a slash command is to to add a `image_url` attribute to the `attachments` object, and then slack will automatically embed the image in the message. For reference - [docs on attachments](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments). So what I'm doing is having two endpoints - one for the slash command and one for fetching the images.

The issue with this is that I would prefer if at all possible to not have the images accessible from outside my slack team. With slash commands, you can use the `token` in the request to validate that the request is coming from slack, and the `team_id` to validate that it came from your team. However, when I use the above method to attach a URL to an image, the GET request that slack sends to that URL cannot be validated in the same way.

My question is - can I somehow embed the image in the response to a slash command? So that I can only serve the images once its been validated the request came from my slack team.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned the only way to include an image in a slash response is as URL in an attachment.

One way of limiting accessibility of an image to members of your Slack team is by using only images that have been previously uploaded (and shared) on your Slack team. Just include the `url_private` URL from the file object in your attachment.

Comment: @Norsul Ronsul if this answer helped you, please consider marking it as solution, so we can close this question. Thank you!